# Grid columns not aligning property when using grid-template-areas?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to create a template for the webpage I am designing and hope to have it in the following format:

[image: Requested Format]

I believe I have set up the grid-template-areas correctly, but looking at the html file in the browser (also seen in the image above) that even though some of the numbers were placed into the grid in the same column (but different row) that they do not align with each other (i.e. the 5 and 6 being off by one white space as well as 8 and 9).

Am I doing something wrong or is there a piece of code I am missing to make sure that the grid-areas are aligning with each other? I've tried manually placing the items in the grid with the grid-column-start/end and grid-row-start/end commands but I continue to get the same problem.

```css
body{
 font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}

.wrapper{
 display:grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(autofit,6,1fr);
 grid-auto-rows:minmax(100px,auto);
 grid-template-areas:
 "top-bar"
 "second-bar"
 "navmenu"
 "third-bar"
 "last-bar";
}

.top-bar{
 grid-area: top-bar;
 display:grid;
 grid-template-areas:
 ". links links . search-bar .";
}

.links{
 grid-area: links;
}

.search-bar{
 grid-area: search-bar;
}

.second-bar{
 grid-area: second-bar;
 display:grid;
 grid-template-areas:
 ". logo logo title title .";
}

.logo{
 grid-area:logo;
}

.title{
 grid-area:title;
}

.navmenu{
 grid-area: navmenu;
 display:grid;
 grid-template-areas:
 ". nav-bar nav-bar nav-bar nav-bar ."
}

.nav-bar{
 grid-area:nav-bar;
}

.third-bar{
 grid-area: third-bar;
 display:grid;
 grid-template-areas:
 ". images images images images ."
 ". quick-links what-we-do what-we-do what-we-do ."
}

.images{
 grid-area:images;
}

.quick-links{
 grid-area:quick-links;
}

.what-we-do{
 grid-area:what-we-do;
}

.last-bar{
 grid-area: last-bar;
 display:grid;
 grid-template-areas:
 ". . footer footer footer ."
}

.footer{
 grid-area:footer;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testpracticecss.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">

<div class="top-bar">
 <div class = "links">1</div>
 <div class = "search-bar">2</div>
</div>

<div class="second-bar">
 <div class="logo">3</div>
 <div class="title">4</div>
</div>

<div class="navmenu">
  <div class="nav-bar">5</div>
</div>

<div class = "third-bar">
 <div class="images">6</div>
 <div class="quick-links">7</div>
 <div class="what-we-do">8</div>
</div>

<div class = "last-bar">
 <div class="footer">9</div>
</div>

</div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('frmSearch').onsubmit = function() {
        window.location = document.getElementById('select1').value + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm wondering if you used the grid according to the documentation. Also when removing the '7' element, the problem seems fixed. Maybe take a second look to it with the docs of css grid in front of you

Comment: For starters, your primary container rule `grid-template-columns: repeat(autofit,6,1fr)` is invalid. The `repeat()` function takes only two arguments. You have 3. https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#repeat-syntax